# Adding 180 to a number in a cell

Tags: r, sum, cell

I have a dataset in R, and the coordinates are set to "+proj=longlat"

I simply have to add 180 to the number in the cell for one column in R

Simply:

```
  V1
-140.0000
```

needs to read

```
40.0000
```

In excel, it would be creating a new column, and inputting the function: =(V1+180), hitting Enter and then dragging the cell down to replicate this for the rest of the cells in V1.

So simple, yet so hard. Please assist!

Comment: if `dat` is the data and you need to add to the first element of column `V1` you could try `dat$V1[1] <- dat$V1[1]+180`

Comment: @akrun, I think he want the whole column, i.e., `dat$V1 <- dat$V1 + 180`

Comment: I have upvoted this question. The fact that it is a simple question does not make it less valid. What the question of the OP is is actually quite clear.

Comment: clear, yes.  Research effort?  Useful? I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you want to add 180 to a number in a variable, you can simply do:

```
a = -140
b = a + 180
a
[1] -140
b
[1] 40
```

To apply this to an entire column, simply do:

```
dat = data.frame(lat = sort(runif(100) * 180))
dat$new_col = dat$lat + 180
head(dat)
        lat  new_col
1  1.170811 181.1708
2  9.104993 189.1050
3  9.179259 189.1793
4 11.475814 191.4758
5 11.502220 191.5022
6 11.716903 191.7169
```

Notice that when you add one number (`180`) to a vector (`dat$lat`), R interprets that as you meaning to add `180` to each of the elements of `dat$lat`. This is referred to as vectorisation.

Comment: thank you very much! I don't use stackoverflow much, my apologies I did not reply sooner